# Finding an Image Icon Next to a Text Item in Watir-WebDriver

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir-webdriver

The context is I'm using watir-webdriver and I need to locate if an image appears prior to a particular item in a list.

More specifically, there is a section of the site that has articles uploaded to them. Those articles appear in a list. The structure looks like this:

```
<div id="article-resources"
  <ul class="components">
    ...
    <li>
      <div class="component">
        <img src="some/path/article.png">
        <div class="replies">
          <label>Replies</label>
        </div>

        <div class="subject">
          <a href="/article">Saving the Day</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Each article appears as a separate li item. (The ellipses above are just meant to indicate I can have lots of liste items.)

What I want our automation to do is find out if the article has been appropriately given the image article.png. The trick is I need to make sure the actual article -- in the above case, "Saving the Day" -- has the image next to it. I can't just check for the image because there will be multiples.

So I figured I had to use xpath to solve this. Using Firefox to help look at the xpath gave me this:

```
id("article-resources")/x:ul/x:li[2]/x:div/x:img
```

That does me no good, though, because the key discriminator seems to be the li[2], but I can't count on this article always being the second in the list.

So I tried this:

```
article_image = '//div[@class="component"]/a[contains(.,"Saving the Day")]/../img'
@browser.image(:xpath => article_image).exist?.should be_true
```

The output I get is:

```
expected: true value
got: false (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

So it's not finding the image which likely means I'm doing something wrong since I'm certain the test is on the correct page.

My thinking was I could use the above to get any link (a) tags in the div area referenced as class "component". Check if the link has the text and then "back up" one level to see if an image is there.

I'm not even checking the exact image, which I probably should be. I'm just checking if there's an image at all.

So I guess my questions are:

- What am I doing wrong with my XPath?
- Is this even the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Watir**

There are a couple of approaches possible.

One way would be find the link, go up to the component div and then check for the image:

```
browser.link(:text => 'Saving the Day').parent.parent.image.present?
```

or

```
browser.div(:class => 'subject', :text => 'Saving the Day').parent.image.present?
```

Another approach, which is a little more robust to changes, is to find the component div that contains the link:

```
browser.divs(:class => 'component').find { |component|
  component.div(:class => 'subject', :text => 'Saving the Day').exists?
}.image.present?
```

**Using XPath**

The above could of course be done through xpath as well.

Here is your corrected xpath:

```
article_image = '//div[@class="component"]//a[contains(.,"Saving the Day")]/../../img'
puts browser.image(:xpath => article_image).present?
```

Or alternatively:

```
article_image = '//a[contains(.,"Saving the Day")]/../../img'
browser.image(:xpath => article_image).present?
```

Again, there is also the top down approach:

```
article_image = '//div[@class="component"][//a[contains(.,"Saving the Day")]]/img'
browser.image(:xpath => article_image).present?
```

You can read more about these approaches and other options in the book [Watirways](https://leanpub.com/watirways/read#leanpub-auto-locating-an-element).

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. You have my deepest thanks for your response. I am looking into the Watirways reference you mentioned as well. Thank you for your assistance.